# Create Parallax Background Using Snap.svg

Tags: html, css, svg, parallax, snap.svg

I have created an `svg` using [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/). I intend to use this `svg` as part of a parallax background. Is my approach to using snapsvg as a parallax background correct?

```js
var s = Snap("#svgout");
s.attr({
  viewBox: "0 0 600 100"
});

//lets draw 2 rects at position 100,100 and then reposition them

var r = s.rect(100, 100, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  stroke: '#123456','strokeWidth': 20,fill: 'red','opacity': 0.2
});

var r = s.rect(10, 10, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  stroke: '#123456','strokeWidth': 20,fill: 'red','opacity': 0.2
});

var r = s.rect(200, 10, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  stroke: '#123456','strokeWidth': 20,fill: 'red','opacity': 0.2
});

var r = s.rect(300, 100, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  stroke: '#123456','strokeWidth': 20,fill: 'red','opacity': 0.2
});

var r = s.rect(400, 10, 100, 100, 20, 20).attr({
  stroke: '#123456','strokeWidth': 20,fill: 'red','opacity': 0.2
});
```

```css
#svgout {
  width: 100%;
}
#about {
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  position: relative;
}
#about svg {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<header style="height:100px; background:#000">
  <div>header content</div>
</header>

<section data-type="background" id="about">
  <svg id="svgout"></svg>
  content to add within the parrallax
</section>

<section style="height:400px ; background:#f1c40f">
  <div>main content</div>
</section>
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fwjmtwz/)

Comment: You could try a CSS 3D transform. SVG and snapsvg on their own will not do 3D.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you illustrate this on a fiddle. Im new to 3D transforms or any tutorial i can refer to that is related?

Comment: @RobertLongson i will add my work if clarifications are required

Comment: Just wondering, why not use one of the parallax scripts out there ? What are you specifically trying to achieve with Snap ?